# validations not working when create triggered from outside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following in a view (`user.html.haml`) that is outside of the `apps_controller` and `App` model:

```
#myModal.modal.hide.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
            .modal-header
              %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
              %h3#myModalLabel Add Mobile App
              = form_for @app, class: 'modal-body' do |f|
                = f.label :name, class: 'pull-left'
                = f.text_field :name, style: 'width: 500px;'

                .modal-footer
                  %button.btn{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal"} Close
                  = f.submit "Save App", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

This currently saves the data into the `App` model successfully, but it is not triggering the validations that I have in the `App` model.

Is there a reason why validations will not work when records are being generated in a view that is not the same as the model?

Comment: No. From what i understand validations should work regardless of the view you use to create the record

Comment: For some reason I have the following validation for name: `validates :name, :presence => true` yet in the form I'm submitting it will still create the record when it's empty.

Comment: Does the validates work otherwise?

Comment: in the console it's working

Comment: oh dont have any idea then.. sorry..

Comment: can you show your code for the saving? just calling `.save` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `form_for` is generating correctly the url for your `create` action? We need the `app_controller` code and `routes.rb`.